# Correct usage of "is" or "are" in this sentence

Tags: grammar

Which is the correct usage?

Another thing to consider *is* your search results.

Another thing to consider *are* your search results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

"Is" is correct because the subject ("another thing") is singular. The verb reflects the subject and not the object of a sentence.

Comment: Right; but technically "your search results" is a complement and not an object in the OP's sentence.

Answer (score 0):

For sure'**is**' as  the singular subject takes a singular verb. It has nothing to do with the object.

Ex.
The prize ***was*** a car and some money.
The most important thing in my life ***is*** my friends

Comment: Right; but technically "your search results" is a complement and not an object in the OP's sentence.